# How to get storybook to pick up custom events

Tags: storybook

I have an input web component utilizing ShadowDOM, that internally has a simple structure:

```html
<custom-input id="foobar">
  ::shadow
    <div id="input-root" class="label-north">
      <label for="input">Labeltext</label>
      <input id="input" type="text" />
    </div>
  ::endshadow
</custom-input>
```

Whenever the native `change` event occurs, I am replacing this native `change` event with a custom `state-changed` event that reports the component state in the `event.detail` payload. This event has `composed: true` and `bubbles: true`.

How do I get this custom event object to show up in the `actions` section in Storybook?

I have tried like this:

```js
    parameters: {
        actions: {
            handles: ['state-changed'],
        },
    },
```

But nothing shows up in `actions` when I change the value of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the cause for the issue:

My web component would check if it has an `id`, as that is a core part of the `event.detail` payload. If none was present, I stopped emitting the  `state-change` and instead issued a `console.warn("Component cannot meaningfully report its state change as no id is present.", this)`.

As this warning didn't show up in the console (maybe because it's issued in an `iframe`?), I wasn't aware of the problem.

Once I gave all components an `id` it did work as described in the question.